# Powershell script to send SMTP email fails

Tags: smtpclient

I am attempting to use .net to send and email via powershell.

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At line:1 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

Using the following script:

```
$EmailFrom = "myemail@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "anotheremail@gmail.com"
$Subject = "test" 
$Body = @"
test
"@
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 25) 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

What could be causing this exception? Thanks!

Comment: Or you could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: It looks like that would work. I need to learn how to create a cmdlet from the provided powershell script.  If the cmdlet works, wouldn't the inline script work just as well?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$EmailTo = "myself@gmail.com"
$EmailFrom = "me@mydomain.com"
$Subject = "Test" 
$Body = "Test Body" 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
$SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```